# How to wait for MSSQL in Docker Compose?

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have a *service* (an ASP.NET Core Web application) that depends on MSSQL. The services are orchestrated using Docker compose, and I want docker compose to first start the database and wait for it to be **ready** before running my service. For that, I am defining the `docker-compose.yml` as:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  sql.data:
    container_name: db_service
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-S", "http://localhost:1433", "-U", "sa", "-P", "Pass_word", "-Q", "SELECT 1", "||", "exit 1"]

  my_service:
    container_name: my_service_container
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}my_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
```

With this health-check, Docker compose does not wait for the database service to be ready, and starts `my_service` immediately after, and, as expected, `my_service` fails connecting to the database. Part of the log is:

```bsh
Recreating db_service ... done
Recreating my_service_container ... done
Attaching to db_service, my_service_container 
my_service_container | info: ...Context[0]
my_service_container |       Migrating database associated with context Context
my_service_container | info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
my_service_container |       Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 initialized 'Context' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=MyService
my_service_container | fail: Context[0]
my_service_container |       An error occurred while migrating the database used on context Context
my_service_container | Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
...
exception details
...
my_service_container | ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
my_service_container exited with code 0
db_service | 2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)
        Nov 30 2018 12:57:58
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      All rights reserved.
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      Server process ID is 4120.
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2020-03-05 05:45:51.82 Server      Registry startup parameters:
         -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
         -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
         -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
```

As shown in the logs, the docker compose first starts the DB, but does not wait for it become ready before running my service.

I tried different syntax for the `healthcheck`, e.g.,:

```
test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S http://localhost:1433 -U sa -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -Q "SELECT 1" || exit 1
```

But neither worked as expected.

I have checked the following sources online, but using neither I was able to solve the problem:

- [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854997/947889)
- [github comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/133#issuecomment-382635343)
- [github sample](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/1d93e1e66ffd633058fb6be9da68877baae7237d/samples/development-frameworks/SqlServerOnDocker/docker-compose.yml#L14)

Is this functionality even supported in `version 3.7`? [because of this confusing comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30404#issuecomment-323212621)

---

### Question

Any thoughts on how best I can wait for MSSQL service to start?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After searching and trying many different scenarios, I was able to add waiting using the following composer file. This is for `asp.net` core solution. The key is that you have to overwrite `entrypoint` if it is specified in `dockerfile`. Also, you need to make sure to save "wait-for-it.sh" LF as line ending instead of CRLF, otherwise you'll get the error of `file not found`.

The `dockerfile` should have the following (download it from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh, make sure to save the file):

```
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  vc-db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_SQL_PORT:-1433}:1433"
    expose:  
      - 1433  
    environment: 
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Express
      - SA_PASSWORD=v!rto_Labs!
    networks:
      - virto

  vc-platform-web:
    image: virtocommerce/platform:${DOCKER_TAG:-latest}
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_PLATFORM_PORT:-8090}:80"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+
    depends_on:
      - vc-db
    entrypoint: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "vc-db:1433", "-t", "120", "--", "dotnet", "VirtoCommerce.Platform.Web.dll"]
    networks:
      - virto
```

Comment: How to connect internal mssql DB threw docker?
I have server with MSSQL DB in one network with host machine when docker will running. In my simple flask app i use pyodbc connection to DB.
On other app i use sqlite db file with docker and it was simple to connect it.

Comment: I feel that this "wait-for" and similar are semi-solution: what if container/sql-container can not be started due a bug or, really, any reason. Are we going to wait forever? Or if we are using timeout, how can we be sure this timeout is enough in a given particular environment?

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I think it is reasonable for it to wait until related service becomes available, it is a job of a scheduler at that point to throw the error. Timeout is a hack since we really don't know how long would it take for service to start.

Answer (score 9):

When you use `depends_on`, docker-compose will just launch your base service with more priority and never wait for start services.

There are some useful external program that help you to wait for specific service (port), then run another service.

[vishnubob/wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) is one of them which blocks execution flow until your specific port(s) get ready.
Another good choice is [eficode/wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for) which already prepared for docker-compose.

Example usage (according to eficode/wait-for docs)

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4

  backend:
    build: backend
    # Blocks execution flow util db:5432 is ready (Or you can use localhost instead)
    command: sh -c './wait-for db:5432 -- npm start'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**-- UPDATE --**

Consider you have a Python application that depend on a database like PostgreSQL, and also your application will run with this command: `python app.py`
As [Official Docker Document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) said, Put `vishnubob/wait-for-it` in your image (inside of your other project files like `app.py`)

Now just put this lines in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    # This command waits until `db:5432` respond (5432 is default PostgreSQL port)
    # then runs our application by this command: `python app.py`
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Note: Don't forget to put this commands in your `Dockerfile` inside your image files:

```
# Copy wait-for-it.sh into our image
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
# Make it executable, in Linux
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete functional example? e.g., `./wait-for` command should be installed on the `db` image?

Comment: I added the wait-for-it.sh file in the root of my image folder, and when building, Docker  20.10.2 says: chmod: wait-for-it.sh: Operation not permitted on Windows 10 19.09. Any Idea?

Comment: @JoanComasFdz is your container image Windows, chmod is a linux command

Comment: @AjayBhasy I am on Windows 10 1909 with Docker Desktop using linux containers

Comment: @JoanComasFdz I added the script file to my project which resulted it being copied to the publish folder and then in the publish part of Dockerfile before the EntryPoint, I ran this command and it worked

Answer (score 9):

I think your initial attempt isn't actually far off. Using a health check seems the most appropriate route, so I would continue with that approach, however you'll want to take advantage of the `condition` functionality of `depends_on`. With this, you can use `service_healthy` condition, which will wait for your SQL Server health check to report healthy.

See this article on the Docker website which mentions this:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Your `docker-compose.yml` would look like this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  sql.data:
    container_name: db_service
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-S", "http://localhost:1433", "-U", "sa", "-P", "Pass_word", "-Q", "SELECT 1", "||", "exit 1"]

  my_service:
    container_name: my_service_container
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}my_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      sql.data:
        condition: service_healthy
```

You could also take advantage of the `healthcheck` options, as below, and a slightly neater syntax:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  sql.data:
    container_name: db_service
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "Pass_word" -Q "SELECT 1" -b -o /dev/null
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 10
      start_period: 10s

  my_service:
    container_name: my_service_container
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}my_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      sql.data:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: _This_ seems to me like the cleanest approach (besides the [Kubernetes solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365732/1811525))! More information in the [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1).

Comment: See also the [feature request #133](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/133) with additional examples and discussion regarding some edge cases.

Answer (score 6):

Create two separate dockerfiles (e.g):

1. Mssql.Dockerfile
2. App.Dockerfile

Set up the sequence within docker-compose.yml

**Mssql.Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server AS base

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV SA_PASSWORD=Password123

COPY . .
COPY ["Db/Scripts/*", "Db/Scripts/"]
VOLUME ./Db:/var/opt/mssql/data

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=5s --start-period=10s --retries=10 \
    CMD /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S . -U sa -P Password123 -i Db/Scripts/SetupDb.sql || exit 1
```

**App.Dockerfile:**

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["AspNetCoreWebApplication/AspNetCoreWebApplication.csproj", "AspNetCoreWebApplication/"]
    COPY ["WebApp.Data.EF/WebApp.Data.EF.csproj", "WebApp.Data.EF/"]
    COPY ["WebApp.Service/WebApp.Service.csproj", "WebApp.Service/"]

    RUN dotnet restore "AspNetCoreWebApplication/AspNetCoreWebApplication.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/AspNetCoreWebApplication"
    RUN dotnet build "AspNetCoreWebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "AspNetCoreWebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspNetCoreWebApplication.dll"]
```

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    api:
        image: aspnetcore/mentoring_api
        container_name: mentoring_api
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: App.Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        expose: 
            - 8081
        environment:
            ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
        depends_on:
            - sqlserver
    sqlserver:
        image: aspnetcore/mentoring_db
        container_name: mentoring_db
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Mssql.Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        expose: 
            - 1433
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=Password123
        volumes:
            - ./Db:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

**Note:**
The **connection string** will look like: `"Server=sqlserver;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=False;User Id=sa;Password=Password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"`

Comment: You set ENV SA_PASSWORD but then write out the password in the HEALTHCHECK

Comment: Hey @caduceus, why is that a problem?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani why set a variable if you're not going to use it?

Comment: In your previous comment did you intend that the password isn't necessary in `ENV` or in `CMD`?

Comment: Not sure the health-check is going to work without the password provided via health check's `CMD`, maybe I'm wrong but I think both are necessary, worth to check it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete [example](https://github.com/mnadeem/nodejs-opentelemetry-tempo/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml)

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  ms-db-server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
      - ./data/db/mssql/scripts:/scripts/
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    #entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        pid=$$!

        echo "Waiting for MS SQL to be available ⏳"
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S localhost -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P $$SA_PASSWORD -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
        is_up=$$?
        while [ $$is_up -ne 0 ] ; do
          echo -e $$(date)
          /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S localhost -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P $$SA_PASSWORD -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
          is_up=$$?
          sleep 5
        done

        for foo in /scripts/*.sql
          do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $$SA_PASSWORD -l 30 -e -i $$foo
        done
        echo "All scripts have been executed. Waiting for MS SQL(pid $$pid) to terminate."

        wait $$pid

  tempo:
    image: grafana/tempo:latest
    command: ["-config.file=/etc/tempo.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./etc/tempo-local.yaml:/etc/tempo.yaml
      - ./data/tempo-data:/tmp/tempo
    ports:
      - "14268"      # jaeger ingest, Jaeger - Thrift HTTP
      - "14250"      # Jaeger - GRPC
      - "55680"      # OpenTelemetry
      - "3100"       # tempo
      - "6831/udp"   # Jaeger - Thrift Compact
      - "6832/udp"   # Jaeger - Thrift Binary   

  tempo-query:
    image: grafana/tempo-query:latest
    command: ["--grpc-storage-plugin.configuration-file=/etc/tempo-query.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./etc/tempo-query.yaml:/etc/tempo-query.yaml
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"  # jaeger-ui
    depends_on:
      - tempo

  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.1.0
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/loki-local.yaml
    ports:
      - "3101:3100"                                   # loki needs to be exposed so it receives logs
    environment:
      - JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=tempo
      - JAEGER_ENDPOINT=http://tempo:14268/api/traces # send traces to Tempo
      - JAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE=const
      - JAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM=1
    volumes:
      - ./etc/loki-local.yaml:/etc/loki/loki-local.yaml
      - ./data/loki-data:/tmp/loki

  nodejs-otel-tempo-api:
    build: .
    command: './wait-for.sh ms-db-server:1433 -- node ./dist/server.js'
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    environment:
      - OTEL_EXPORTER_JAEGER_ENDPOINT=http://tempo:14268/api/traces
      - OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=nodejs-opentelemetry-tempo
      - LOG_FILE_NAME=/app/logs/nodejs-opentelemetry-tempo.log
      - DB_USER=sa
      - DB_PASS=P@ssw0rd
      - DB_SERVER=ms-db-server
      - DB_NAME=OtelTempo
    volumes:
      - ./data/logs:/app/logs
      - ./etc/wait-for.sh:/app/bin/wait-for.sh   #https://github.com/eficode/wait-for
    depends_on:
      - ms-db-server
      - tempo-query

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:master-ee9c629
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-local.yaml
    volumes:
      - ./etc/promtail-local.yaml:/etc/promtail/promtail-local.yaml
      - ./data/logs:/app/logs
    depends_on:
      - nodejs-otel-tempo-api
      - loki

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ./etc/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus.yaml
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/prometheus
      - --config.file=/etc/prometheus.yaml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - nodejs-otel-tempo-api

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:7.4.0-ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ./data/grafana-data/datasources:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources
      - ./data/grafana-data/dashboards-provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
      - ./data/grafana-data/dashboards:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - tempo-query
      - loki
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple script, which will be launched in container with your app. For example, you can just set a delay, using `sleep N` ( where N it is a time which is needed for starting your DB), or you can use a `until` cycle in which you to can try to connect to your DB, and when it will be possible, then you can start your app.

I know this is not a perfect solution, but it helped me when I had a similar problem

Comment: Checking connection inside our application is a good idea, but docker document itself recommends using `wait-for-it` and alternative scripts.

Comment: Of course, I do not argue with this, I just offered a simple ( not perfect) solution

Answer (score 0):

Using Kubernetes Deployment, the following probe successfullly identified the ready state:

```
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: 'Y'
          startupProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P "${SA_PASSWORD}" -Q "SELECT \"READY\"" | grep -q "READY"'
            failureThreshold: 15
            periodSeconds: 10
```

You could code this as a livenessProbe with initialDelay if your Kubernetes version is <1.20.

Explanation:
sqlcmd returns a '0' status irrespective of whether the query returns anything or not.   However, `grep -q` returns 0 or 1 depending on presence of the word "READY".

I have not used docker-compose but I suspect this command would work as a healthcheck test (assuming SA_PASSWORD is injected into the environment), ie:

```
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - /bin/sh
        - '-c'
        - '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P "${SA_PASSWORD}" -Q "SELECT \"READY\"" | grep -q "READY"'
```

- [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
- [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also delay the docker startup until mssql is up:

docker-compose.yaml

```
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "t9D4:EHfU6Xgccs-"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    networks:
      - backend
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
        curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh | bash /dev/stdin localhost:1433
```